# Lang under graduate algabra Ⅶ§4 question 17

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, finite-groups, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$,contained in its algebraic closure $A$. Let $σ$ be an automorphism of $A$ over $F$ and Let $K$ be the fixed field. 
>   Prove that every finite extension of $K$ is cyclic.

I could solve like below.

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension , then $[L:K]=2$. So $L/K$ is cyclic.

Is it correct?

Maybe above proof is not correct I can't say$[L:K]=2$.

I started to solve it again. Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension $(L \subset A)$.Then $K$ is a fixed field of $<σ>$. So $L/K$ is cyclic. Let $M/K$ be a finite extension. Let $N/K$ be a Galois closure of $M/K$.$M/K$ is cyclic, so $N/K$ is cyclic. Q.E.D.

Is it correct?

Comment: Why would $[L:K]=2$?

Comment: Do you know the [Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory)?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Mayb like this,Let $G$ be a automorphism of $A$. $Gal(A/K)=\{σ∈G | σ(x)=x \forall x∈K\}.$

Comment: There’s no reason why the field extension degree must be $2$.

Comment: @Lubin　I just thought order of $σ$ is order "2". In general, $σ$ is not order "2". So it is not correct.